# python random sampling from list and exporting to txt

Tags: python, list, random, export-to-csv

I would like to extract several random combinations of strings from a list and store the results in a .csv or .txt

with this code I extract the first combination. Is it possible to add a loop for having 10 extractions without replacement, and each extractions will be a row in a csv?

```
import random

items = ['here', 'are', 'some', 'strings', 'of',
     'which', 'we', 'will', 'select', 'one']


rand_items = [items[random.randrange(len(items))]
          for item in range(7)]

print(rand_items)
```

Comment: Yes, you can write a for loop to do something ten times. Have you actually *tried* that? What happened?

Comment: i forgot to mention without replacement, 7 unique strings

Comment: *"Have you actually tried that? What happened?"* Also how can you select seven items without replacement ten times from a list of ten items?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import random

items = set(['here', 'are', 'some', 'strings', 'of', 'which', 'we', 'will', 'select', 'one'])
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for _ in range(10):
        spamwriter.writerow(random.sample(items, 7))
```

**random.sample(population, k)**
Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Comment: i forgot to mention without replacement. that was the problem, I don't want repetitions such as we,we,of,of,which,of,of